# Jquery replace div and reset code upon menu <a href>select</a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I have jquery script which replaces a div when `a href="#1"` is selected. `a href="#1"` is also replaced by `a href="#2"` and vice versa. Here is the Jquery:

```
$('.child2, a[href="#1"]').hide()

$('#replacepagelinks a').click(function(){
    $(this).hide().siblings().show()
    var w = this.hash.replace('#', '');
    $('#parent div.child'+w).show().siblings().hide()
})
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
<div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
</div>
<div id="replacepagelinks">
<a href="#1">Replace Child 1 with Child 2</a>
<a href="#2">Replace Child 2 with Child 1</a>
</div>
```

Here is the jfiddle working example http://jsfiddle.net/KaqZ5/

This works great for 1 instance. However i have these positioned multiple times in a jquery menu and this causes the problem. If i click the first menu item it reveals child1 and clicking `a href="#1"` to reveal child2 does so as expected. But now if i go into the second menu item child2 is still displaying (not child1 as it should!) as the jquery code has not been reset. Here is my html setup:

```
<div id=menu">
     <div class="menu_item">
          <a href="#" class="drop_menu"></a>
           <div id="parent">
              <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
              <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
           </div>
           <div id="replacepagelinks">
              <a href="#1">Replace Child 1 with Child 2</a>
              <a href="#2">Replace Child 2 with Child 1</a>
           </div>
     </div>
     <div class="menu_item">
          <a href="#" class="drop_menu"></a>
           <div id="parent">
              <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
              <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
           </div>
           <div id="replacepagelinks">
              <a href="#1">Replace Child 1 with Child 2</a>
              <a href="#2">Replace Child 2 with Child 1</a>
           </div>
     </div>
     <div class="menu_item"> etc.. </div>
</div>
```

In order to drop reveal each menu_item i have an `a href="#" class="drop_menu` which performs the menu drop jquery. Is there any way to have the same `a href="#" class="drop_menu"` link also reset the 'replace div jquery script' (top of this page) so that every time a menu item is selected child1 is the first to appear? Thanks heaps. Pia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to make sure the `class=child1` and `href=#2` are always shown when you click a `drop_menu` and the others are hidden? Then this would do the trick:

```
$(".drop_menu").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.child1, a[href="#2"]').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: Hi. You DID understand correctly :) Thanks heaps for your help! @st3inn

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/KaqZ5/3/

I changed the first line of your `click` function to:

```
     $('a[href="' + this.hash + '"]').hide().siblings().show()
```

For example: this will hide all the `#1` links and show the `#2` ones.

Answer (score 0):

you should never have two tags with the same id (you have #parent and #replacepagelinks more than once), id should be unique, if you need more than one then you have a class

```
$('#replacepagelinks a').click(function(){
  $(this).hide().siblings().show()
  var w = this.hash.replace('#', '');
  item = $(this).parents('.menu_item'); /*get the parent .menu_item*/
  $(item).find('.child'+w).show().siblings().hide(); /*find the .child and show it*/
})
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this. I have since updated my code with your recommendations in place. @arieljuod